# Class method outputs string message, can't unit test due error citing conversion from void to string not applicable

Tags: c#, unit-testing, compiler-errors

I'm quite new to unit testing. So far, I'm able to successfully unit test methods that return a data type, such as enum types, integer types, and string types. However, I can't seem to unit test void return type methods that outputs a string, it says unable to convert 'void' to string. There isn't a return type. The code below should clarify my problem.
This is the method:

```
public void Details()
    {
        if (_type == AccountType.FixedDeposit)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Fixed Deposit Account:{0,-5}Balance:{1}", _accNumber, _balance));
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-13} Account:{1,-5}Balance:{2}", _type, _accNumber, _balance));
        }
```

This is the unit test code:

```
[TestCase]
    public void TestDetails()
    {
        BankAccount b = new BankAccount(111, AccountType.Saving);
        b.Deposit(1000);
        b.Withdraw(500);
        StringAssert.AreEqualIgnoringCase("Saving       Account:111  Balance:500", b.Details());
    }
```

I expected it to output a string that is able to compare too.

Comment: Console output is not the same thing as return value, your test code tries to compare to a return value

Comment: Why is `Details` a void returning method rather than returning a `string` (possibly it should be an override for `ToString()`) and letting the *caller* determine whether they want to examine the string (unit test) or output it to the Console (presumably, the application)? Don't tie the output method into the class containing *domain* logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `Details` to return the string instead of printing it out:

```
public string Details()
{
    if (_type == AccountType.FixedDeposit)
    {
        return String.Format("Fixed Deposit Account:{0,-5}Balance:{1}", _accNumber, _balance);
    }
    else
    {
        return String.Format("{0,-13} Account:{1,-5}Balance:{2}", _type, _accNumber, _balance);
    }
}
```

Note that you'll have to change your "production" code and add the `Console.WriteLine` calls to the places that called `Details`.